# TFS save/export/import dashboards and queries

Tags: tfs, dashboard

I'm in the process of moving from TFS2012 to TFS2018, and I did a pre-production environment as recommended.  I set up many new queries, dashboards and tons of new widgets to explore and demo the new features.  Now that I want to go live, it's time to bring the latest production data over, but I can see no way to maintain all the dashboards I created.

I tried attaching a new collection database while leaving the new configuration database in place, but that didn't do the trick.

Surely there's a way to do this or experimenting in the pre production environment would be a waste of time.  And you've never have a chance to configure the new features before rolling them out to your teams.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration database doesn't contain anything about dashboards -- it basically exists to store server-level configuration (such as what team project collections are attached, SMTP setup, etc -- the kind of stuff you'd see in the Admin console). The collection database is what stores the dashboards.

The purpose of a pre-production upgrade is to **test** that everything works, not pre-configure things. The expectation is that you configure things after the migration, not before.

That said, you can use the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/dashboard/?view=vsts-rest-4.1) to export/import the dashboard configuration you set up. It's going to require a fair bit of scripting on your part, but it's possible.

Ex: `GET https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/dashboard/dashboards?api-version=4.1-preview.2` will give you a list of dashboards. The API documentation is pretty thorough.

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't know there was an API for this.  But after banging my head on it for a few days, I never got anything useful out of or into it.  For example, it seems the 'get' only returns basic properties rather than the clauses/conditions of the query.  And I never got a 'create' to work even when copied straight from the examples given.  Only about half the error responses contained any info.  (I wonder if not all these are supported by the local instance of TFS?)  So, I'm just going to recreate all queries, widgets and dashboards from scratch over the weekend after the upgrade. :-/